# CodeIgniter loading css and positioning

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am not able to get my external css file working in my codeIgniter view file.
how can i get it done.? I am also loading a template along with the view file.And the css is working fine for the template. But not view.
Also is there anyway i can use to get the relative positioning of the view and controller done together??

and rly Sry guys cant share code.

dir structure:

-application
    -controller
    -model
    -view
-css
-js...

css and js folder are outside application folder.

I am using

<'link href='base_url; ?>/css/style.css' rel="stylesheet">
$this->base_url  = $this->config->item('base_url');

Comment: <link> in view file .

Comment: show code and your dir struture?

Comment: sorry i cant show code fr sme reasons. can u suggest me a link where i can go and figure this out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load JS and CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750100/how-to-load-js-and-css)

Comment: @jai: No i dun a have it css and js folder in my application dir. Its in the root dir.

Comment: and also i using the same syntax as specified in  the answers.It aint working. And my js is working just fine. Juz no css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using site_url() or base_url() functions

You can do it so :

```
<link href="<?=base_url()?>css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

OR

```
 <link href="<?=base_url('css/custom.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

OR

```
 <link href="<?=site_url('css/custom.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You can try any one of these

(**Note**:acc to your dir structure your css dir is at same level as application dir)

Comment: yeah i have done the same. I am using <?php echo $this->base_url?>/css/custom.css. and $base_url = $this->config->item('base_url'); and in my config file i have given the proper definition. Its still not working?

Comment: when am loading js its working juz fine but i dun knw why css effects are not taking place.

Comment: Did you check your browser what path get added when doing <link href="<?=base_url('css/custom.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> On chrome browser hit F12 key to see what assets not get loaded

Comment: yeah i checked. Its what it should be. The link is good. But no effect taking place

Comment: If a css file gets loaded then its styling should work.However if you have another css file gets loaded after that then latter take prefrence .......A debug tip: add a '!mportant' keyword with values       <code><style> #myBox{position:relative !mportant;background:red !important;color:#fff !important;}</code> Note: I just gave them high <b>specificity</b>

Comment: i used !important also.. Still no effect

Comment: i doubt your css not get loading...double check it .Is it the same file you want to link to? If nothing work then you should post your code ..so we can further help ....If something is in the code you dun wanna share with us just place a placeholder for it

Answer (score 1):

Put your css/js/images/etc folders in your root directory. In this way you can add css or any assets to your site. As simple as that.

```
<?php echo base_url("css/style.css"); ?>
```

**UPDATE**: Make sure .htaccess file allows access to these folders.

Comment: yeah dey are in the root directory itself. and yeah i have RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] in my .htaccess file.

Comment: still not getting results?