# Load CSS in codeigniter viewpage only

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I am not sure if this is possible, I want to load CSS and JavaScript inside a view not on *include.php*. I have CSS file loading on *include.php* and its working fine. Now what I want to do is to load it inside a view page named *report.php*.

Here is my CSS and JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/selectboxit/jquery.selectBoxIt.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/datatables/responsive/css/datatables.responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/select2/select2-bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700,400italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/neon-core.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/select2/select2.css">
```

Comment: store this file on within top.php and include that file within your view part

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to load css file in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697954/how-to-load-css-file-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct what your after. You can load css and js in images from views folder, but you would have to modify the htacces in the application to allow the files. Not recommended though. The htaccess in the application folder says **deny all** so is blocking the css images and js.

You could just delete the htaccess in the application folder but may be not secure. Up to you.

Auto load url helper.

**Main Directory where you should store your assets. IE css js and images**

Just examples:

**views/common/header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/stylesheet.css');?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css');?>">
</head>
<body>
```

**views/common/footer.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/custom.js');?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php 

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {

$this->load->view('common/header');
$this->load->view('content/review');
$this->load->view('common/footer');

}

}
```