# How to load CS, JS dynamically in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have different CSS and JS files related to different views.  How to load CSS and JS conditionally or dynamically according to views so that only the respective JS or CSS loads to the browser?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Just create condition on your function. Then send your CSS or JS file location to view.

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    // conditional 
    if (your condition) {
        $this->data = array(
            'css' => site_url() . "your css file",
            'js'  => site_url() . "your js file"
        );
    } else {
        $this->data = array(
            'css' => site_url() . "your other css file",
            'js'  => site_url() . "your other js file"
        );
    }
    $this->load->view('page', $this->data);
}
```

View:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $css; ?>">
<script src="<?php echo $js; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Add the essential part of the answer instead of providing link here

Comment: ok.i will share here.wait a minute.dont forget give me reputation,because its hard to search good site like that in google

Answer (score 2):

Add css and js files to the page from controller, and pass to view using data array. For loop the array and load css and java files from view.
Example given below,

Controller section

```
$styles[1]['css'] = 'plugins/select2/select2.css';
$styles[2]['css'] = 'plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css';
$data['styles']   = $styles;

$scripts[1]['js'] = 'plugins/select2/select2.min.js';
$scripts[2]['js'] = 'plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js';
$data['scripts']  = $scripts;
```

View section

```
{if isset($styles)}
    {foreach from=$styles item=v}
        <link href="{base_url()}assets/{$v.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    {/foreach}
{/if}

{if isset($scripts)}
    {foreach from=$scripts item=v}
        <script src="{base_url()}assets/{$v.js}"></script>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Comment: I'm a CodeIgniter newbie and this (view section) mislead me. CodeIgniter doesn't use template tags. See [CodeIgniter Does Not Require a Template Engine](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/at_a_glance.html#codeigniter-does-not-require-a-template-engine). Although I'm not sure if it can be added manually. So I used the same method, but in plain PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$add_js = array(
    'filename'  => array(BASEJS.'themejs/bootstrap-fileinput.js'),
    'type'      => 'import',
);

$footer = array(
    'set_title'     => MAINTITLE,
    'javascript'    => $add_js,
);

$get_footer = $this->settings->set_footer($footer);
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this. It doesn't explain anything. And it seems like it's a copy/paste from an actual code, which makes it even harder to understand.