# CodeIgniter CSS not working

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter and I'm trying to use some stylesheets.

In my autoload.php I have `$autoload['helper'] = array('html','url');`

and on my view page I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css')?>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css')?>"/>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.js')?>"></script>
```

I'm attempting to use stylesheets from Bootstrap, to make a nav bar appear.

Here is my navbar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="...">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The problem is the CSS doesn't seem to be working at all.

When I look at the page source, the proper links are included to the stylesheets in my `<head></head>` tags, but I get no change on the page itself.

Comment: check the console | network tab.probably css file isn't loaded

Comment: @FastSnail What should I be looking for? It seems that only my javascripts are coming up, I don't see any css files in there. But the links for them when I go into my page source is correct. What should I do?

Comment: network tab in browser console show all files loaded in to your page.so you can see 404 error red mark if some files are missing

Comment: You are missing the type also `type="text/css"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`src` should be `href`.[read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html)

don't use `src` for link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.css')?>"/>
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Nice spot.

Comment: What a way to feel stupid. Did it used to be src? I found the code in question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697954/how-to-load-css-file-in-codeigniter

Comment: It's src for `<script>` tags, which is probably why you were confused.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton it is probably mistake